# Denumerable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If A is a non denumerable set and B is another set and there is an injective function f:B->A.

Does B denumerable or non denumerable or we do not know whether B is denumerable or not?

Comment: Do you mean ["countable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumeration)?

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa: *Denumerable* usually means countably infinite. Although "countable" can mean cardinality $\leq \aleph_0$ or cardinality $= \aleph_0$ (usage varies with the author), I think "denumerable" pretty much always means cardinality $= \aleph_0.$ But for basic questions like this, I do think those asking questions need to be explicit, because unlike for a more advanced question, we don't have other context and assumptions about the OP's background that can help clue us. Unfortunately, it's typically the case that the less one knows, the less one is aware of what might be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "denumerable" you mean "countably infinite" the answer generally is no:

Look at $\mathbb{N}$ (countable) and $\mathbb{R}$ (not countable). The inclusion $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ is injective.
Of course, if we look at the identity function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ both sets involved are not countable.

If $A$ is finite however, $B$ would have to have smaller cardinality than $A$ and hence would also be finite.

If there is an injective function $B\to A$ we generally say that the cardinality of $B$ is smaller or equal to that of $A$.

This wikipedia article might help:
[Cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Definition_2:_%7CA%7C_%E2%89%A4_%7CB%7C)